# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion

> We don't need to have an answer to this now. It's just a good thing to start thinking about soon.

What should our FAQ contain?

For example and inspiration, here's Super User's FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users.
> If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

What should ours look like?

Comment: we dont have an FAQ, we have an about page though. FAQ was nerfed a while ago

Comment: FAQ is used to refer to what should and shouldn't be asked here. It's now contained in the about page, but that doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking something like this:

> Space Exploration Stack Exchange is for space engineers, scientists, and enthusiasts.
>
> If you have a question about …
>
> - space exploration
> - the effect of space on humans, as it pertains to space exploration
> - potential systems that could be used for space exploration
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - basic physics, such as why an ion engine works
> - weather on Earth, except insofar as it interfaces with space exploration

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the key things to not bog down the site are general science, and exosolar objects (Beyond the orbit of the sun).

> If you have a question about …
>
> - space exploration
> - Satellite Design and Operations
> - potential systems that could be used in space
> - Science discovered by space probes
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - Study of exosolar objects, except as they relate to space travel.
> - Physical Sciences, such as geology, astronomy, meteorology, except how they relate to spacecraft.

Comment: Might be easier to read if you use the quotation syntax for that. There's some nice ideas in there.

Comment: @Undo: Thanks, getting the syntax right can sometimes be tricky...